# .net MVC 4 RavenDB Unit Test Controller OnActionExecuting not firing

Tags: asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, controller, abstract-class, ravendb

Using .Net MVC 4, RavenDB, MSTest.

I followed the RavenDB documentation to create an abstract controller class that creates the RavenSession in OnActionExecuting(), and saves the data in OnActionExecuted().

I'm trying to unit test my controller, but the OnActionExecuting() and OnActionExecuted() methods never fire. This means that a session is never created, and I cannot access the database-thus the unit test fails.

In the unit test, I am calling the controller method as follows:

```
PersonController controller = new PersonController();            
JsonResult result = controller.GetPerson("people/1");
```

**PersonController.GetPerson** fires, but quickly hits an error when RavenSession has no value (it's supposed to be instantiated in the abstract class methods mentioned above).

**PersonController** is derived from the abstract class **RavenController**.  **Raven Controller** has the OnActionExecuting() and OnActionExecuted() methods defined, but they are never called.

Should I be calling the controller method another way in my unit test?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up adding the following code to my **PersonController**

```
 private IDocumentSession _RavenSession = null;
    public  IDocumentSession RavenSession
    {
        get
        {
            return _RavenSession ?? base.RavenSession;
        }
        set
        {
            _RavenSession = value;
        }
    }
```

Now I can create a new session when I instantiate the controller in the unit test. I get a warning that I'm hiding an inherited member, but it works fine.